# Error encountered with jenkins properties step

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-workflow, jenkins-pipeline

In my Jnekinsfile, I have the following steps:

```
 properties([[$class: 'ParametersDefinitionProperty', parameterDefinitions: [[$class: 'StringParameterDefinition', defaultValue: 'master', name: 'apiBranchName']]]])
sh "ruby ./build/script '${apiBranchName}'"
```

It works sometimes but in some other time it raises:

```
Groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: apiBranchName for class: groovy.lang.Binding
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. I have several steps that require different parameters. So originally I define only those needed `properties` for each step. (for example, test step requires `apiBranchName` and deploy requires `target`. So I define only `apiBranchName` in tests and only `target` in deploy). That caused the issue.

Once I just define them all on each step it works out fine